# 2D array bounds checking using std::vector and .at()

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I've a quite simple question but for witch I cannot find the answer.

How can I use the `.at(i)` in a 2D array of `vector < vector <type> >` ?

I want to have bounds checking - witch `.at(i)` function provides automatically, but I can only access my array using the `array[i][j]` witch doesn't provide for bounds checking.

Comment: It's a vector of vectors. Just substitute `[...]` by `.at(...)`. How else should it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vec.at(i).at(j)` and must use this in `try-catch` block since `at()` will throw `std::out_of_range` exception if the index is invalid:

```
try
{
      T & item = vec.at(i).at(j);
}
catch(const std::out_of_range & e)
{
     std::cout << "either index i or j is out of range" << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT:

As you said in the comment:

> I actually want the program to stop in case the exception is raised. – jbssm 5 mins ago

In that case, you can *rethrow* in the `catch` block after printing the message that it went out of range, so that you can know the reason why it stopped. And here is how you *rethrow*:

```
catch(const std::out_of_range & e)
{
     std::cout << "either index i or j is out of range" << std::endl;
     throw; //it rethrows the excetion
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually want the program to stop in case the exception is raised.

Comment: In that case, you can *rethrow* in the `catch` block after printing the message that it went out of range, so that you can know the reason why it stopped.

Comment: In that case, don't try/catch at all.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax to use is:

```
array.at(i).at(j)
```

Comment: You are right. I had tried that for starters but made other mistake and didn't complite, so I tought that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since `.at(i)` will return a reference to the `vector` at `v[i]`, use `.at(i).at(j)`.

Comment: You are right. I had tried that for starters but made other mistake and didn't compile, so I tough that was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Reading compiler errors is in equal parts skill and art ... good luck :-)